# Simulating form change in Enzyme/React unit test isn't changing field value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm making some basic form interaction tests

```
const setup = (errors=false) => {
  let props = {
    budget: {}, errors: {},
    onChange: () => {},
    onSave: () => {}
  };

  if (errors === true) {
    props.errors.budgetCategory= "error";
  }

  return shallow(<AddBudgetForm {...props} />);
};


describe("Fluctuating errors based on input values", () => {
  it("Renders an error when a number is present in the cost field", () => {
    let wrapper = setup();
    wrapper.find('[name="budgetCategory"]').simulate('change', { target: { value: '7' } });
    console.log(wrapper.find('[name="budgetCategory"]').props());
  });
});
```

I analyze the props on the console and see that the `value` field is still undefined...

```
{ className: 'form-control',
  placeholder: 'Enter Name of Budget Category',
  onChange: [Function: onChange],
  value: undefined,
  name: 'budgetCategory' }
```

Ideally what I am trying to test is that simulating the key presses of something that isn't a number should trigger the onChange handler to propogate errors to the form.

I tried adding a new onChange handler in the setup, but didn't work:

```
  let props = {
    budget: {}, errors: {},
    onChange: (e) => {props.budget.budgetCategory = e.target.value;},
    onSave: () => {}
  };
```

## AddBudgetForm component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Alert from '../common/Alert';
import TextInput from '../common/TextInput';

const renderDays = () => {
  return Array(31).fill().map((_, i = 1) => <option key={i+1}>{i+1}</option>);
};

const errorsInForm = errors => {
  let error = false;
  Object.keys(errors).map(item => {
    if (errors[item]) { error = true; }
  });

  return error;
};

const generateValidationError = error => {
  return (
    <span style={{color: "red"}}>{error}</span>
  );
};

const AddBudgetForm = ({budget, onChange, onSave, errors}) => {
  return (
    <div name="AddBudgetForm">
      <form>
      {!errorsInForm(errors) &&
        <Alert
          name="add-budget-alert"
          alertType = "alert alert-info"
          fontAwesomeIcon = "fa fa-info"
          alertDescription = " Adding a budget is simple. Add a category such as groceries
          , allocate $200.00 per month and the day you'd like the budget to reset."
        />
      }

      {errorsInForm(errors) &&
        <Alert
          name="add-budget-alert"
          alertType = "alert alert-danger"
          fontAwesomeIcon = "fa fa-warning"
          alertDescription = " There are problems with the form submission. Ensure all values in the form are valid."
        />
      }

    <TextInput
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Name of Budget Category"
        onChange={onChange}
        value={budget.category}
        name="budgetCategory"
      />
    {errors.budgetCategory != "" && generateValidationError(errors.budgetCategory)}

      <div className="form-group input-group">
        <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-usd"></i></span>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Monthly Budget Cost"
          onChange={onChange}
          value={budget.cost}
          name="budgetCost"
        />
      </div>
    {errors.budgetCost != "" && generateValidationError(errors.budgetCost)}

      <select
        className="form-control"
        onChange={onChange}
        value={budget.date}
        name="budgetDate"
      >
        <option>Select Day of Month Budget Item is Due</option>
          {renderDays()}
      </select>
    {errors.budgetDate != "" && generateValidationError(errors.budgetDate)}

      <br/>
      {(!errorsInForm(errors)) &&
        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onClick={() => onSave(budget)}>Add Budget</button>
      }
      {(errorsInForm(errors)) &&
        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" disabled>Fix Form Errors</button>
      }
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

AddBudgetForm.propTypes = {
  budget: PropTypes.object,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  onSave: PropTypes.func,
  errors: PropTypes.object
};

export default AddBudgetForm;
```

Comment: this should work fine - what is wrapper.find('[name="budgetCategory"]').length if you console.log it?

Comment: Length is 1, plus the above object that I wrote in the OP is a result of logging that wrapper.find return value. Just not sure why value remains undefined...

Comment: @ArslArsl I am shallow rendering this component, is that a prob?

Comment: @ArslArsl Unless of course it's because I am passing in a custom onChange handler as a prop which is a function that does nothing,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html), the `.simulate()` method only affects the event prop for the event you are simulating. In this case, the synthetic event args you passed will only be supplied to your `onChange()` function. The actual `value` props will be unaffected.

To confirm, simply update your custom `onChange()` handler to `console.log` the event object supplied to it, e.g.

```
let props = {
    budget: {}, errors: {},
    onChange: (event) => { console.log(event); },
    onSave: () => {}
};
```

Another gotcha on this, is that normal event bubbling won't happen with this simulation -- make sure to run the `.simulate()` method directly on the node you want to trigger the event.

**Refactored AddBudgetForm**
NB: These are just minor suggestions, and are not necessarily the only *correct* way to do it.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Alert from '../common/Alert';
import TextInput from '../common/TextInput';

const renderDays = () => Array(31).fill().map( 
    (_, i = 1) => <option key={i+1}>{i+1}</option> 
);

/**
 * Returns true if a key has a non-null value.
 * @param  {Object} errors - Errors object
 * @return {Boolean} Is there an error?
 */
const errorsInForm = errors => 
    Object.keys(errors).reduce( (hasError, item) => hasError || item != null, false);

const generateValidationError = error => <span style={{color: "red"}}>{error}</span>;

const AddBudgetForm = ({ budget, onChange, onSave, errors = {} }) => (
  <div name="AddBudgetForm">
    <form>
    { ! errorsInForm(errors)
      ? (
      <Alert
        name="add-budget-alert"
        alertType = "alert alert-info"
        fontAwesomeIcon = "fa fa-info"
        alertDescription = " Adding a budget is simple. Add a category such as groceries
        , allocate $200.00 per month and the day you'd like the budget to reset."
      />)
      : (
      <Alert
        name="add-budget-alert"
        alertType = "alert alert-danger"
        fontAwesomeIcon = "fa fa-warning"
        alertDescription = " There are problems with the form submission. Ensure all values in the form are valid."
      />
      )
    }

  <TextInput
      className="form-control"
      placeholder="Enter Name of Budget Category"
      onChange={onChange}
      value={budget.category}
      name="budgetCategory"
    />
  { errors.budgetCategory != "" && 
    generateValidationError(errors.budgetCategory)
  }

    <div className="form-group input-group">
      <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-usd"></i></span>
      <input
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Monthly Budget Cost"
        onChange={onChange}
        value={budget.cost}
        name="budgetCost"
      />
    </div>
  { errors.budgetCost != "" && 
    generateValidationError(errors.budgetCost) 
  }

    <select
      className="form-control"
      onChange={onChange}
      value={budget.date}
      name="budgetDate"
    >
      <option>Select Day of Month Budget Item is Due</option>
        { renderDays() }
    </select>
  { errors.budgetDate != "" && 
    generateValidationError(errors.budgetDate)
  }

    <br/>
    { ! errorsInForm(errors) 
      ? <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onClick={() => onSave(budget)}>Add Budget</button>
      : <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" disabled>Fix Form Errors</button>
    }
    </form>
  </div>
);

AddBudgetForm.propTypes = {
  budget: PropTypes.object,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  onSave: PropTypes.func,
  errors: PropTypes.object
};

export default AddBudgetForm;
```

Comment: Can you provide an example fix? I see that I am logging the proper event in the onChange handler, but setting a new value into the budgetObject within that handler doesn't actually affect anything.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand what you are aiming for. Can you maybe clarify what you need within this test. thanks

Comment: Yes, I want to insert something that is a number and see that a) the value in the input after simulation is a number and b) the component re-renders with my error message

Comment: Cool. Can you add the code for your AddBudgetForm component

Comment: Added, bit large

Comment: I probably would not test `a)` as you would be just testing the enzyme method at that point. For `b)` I would probably -- based on your component -- update the props, in particular the `error` object directly. See `.setProps()` method. Then you could test for the presence of your error message

Comment: Ok, that actually seems logical, not sure why I was overcomplicating things. How does that component look, super ugly or normal?

Comment: It looks fine, always scope for refinements. One thing, I'm not sure how you are using the `errorsInForm` function. I can maybe add a refactor of the component to my answer for reference, if it would help?

Comment: Yah, that would be great. Errors in form simply analyzes the errors object to see if a particular key isn't null. If it's not null, then it means there is an error. If there is an error, then the <span> for errors gets rendered. Might seem a bit clunky though..

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it resolves your question :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using a selector that targets actual DOM element right `wrapper.find('[name="budgetCategory"]')`. I assume that inside `TextInput` you have an input that gets the same `name`. Why not select the `TextInput` directly and call its prop like for example:

```
wrapper.find('TextInput').prop('onChange')(<some value here>)
```